# Application identity not set Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

I have just converted a project to VS2010 and I now starting to see Exceptions in my software in IntelliTrace.

One such Exception is 'Application identity is not set', this occurs whenever my software see's something like

```
string m_AppPath = Application.UserAppDataPath;
```

This isn't a problem as the AppDataPath returns correctly, I'm just wondering why this happens.

The code is in the Main function of Program.cs (if that makes a difference), once out of the Program.cs file and into MainWindow.cs the code works.

My main issue is that I setup Logging prior to the application starting.  Any help appreciated as searching the web doesn't really help.

Paul

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If the problem is occuring in debugging you can first check if the debugger is attached before accessing any application settings:

```
If System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached then
       Me.Text = "Debug Mode"
Else 
       Me.Text = "Version " & My.Application.Deployment.CurrentVersion.ToString
End If
```

Comment: Doing this my path is never set in debug mode.

Answer (score 65):

I found that this problem exists only if you untick "Just My Code" under debug options.

Comment: Perfect answer! I've been plagued by this error on and off for the last month, and this tip finally fixed it!

Comment: Solves the issue, but what does this option do? It hides me more exceptions, not only this one...

Comment: So, if `this problem exists only if you untick "Just My Code" `, then there should not be a problem if "Just My Code" is ticked, right? Well, in a VS2017 project, I have "Just My Code" ticked, and I still get this error when I start debugging.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It's been a long while since I answered this, so pretty hard for me to jump back in and help you. Different firm, different stack.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a ClickOnce application being debugged, another option is to check the `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` setting.

Comment: Checking this property will generate a exception also